# R - geom_bar not producing correct values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a fairly simple stacked histogram with geom_bar but the values on the vertical do not reflect the values passed to the call to ggplot.

the code I'm using:

```
p<-ggplot(data0, aes(x=variable, y=as.numeric(value), fill=season) )
p+geom_bar(stat='identity')+  facet_grid(specie~region) + ...
```

where `str(data0)` reads:

```
'data.frame':   720 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ specie  : Factor w/ 5 levels "","ozone.DU",..: 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ season  : Factor w/ 5 levels "","autumn (SON)",..: 3 4 2 5 3 4 2 5 3 4 ...
 $ region  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 15 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : Factor w/ 736 levels "","1.872389649",..: 28 35 20 12 26 33 19 11 5
```

The bars produces do not reflect any value of the dataframe, and rise constantly with the value!

[the values of the bars are not what I'd expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGcmp.png)

any suggestion is welcome. Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information. (This question is likely of limited use in the future since the problem is not related to ggplot2.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with `as.numeric` of a factor. You're not going to be obtaining the numeric value of the factor but rather the ordered value of the factor. Do `test <- as.numeric(data0$value)` and look at the result of the `test`.

What you need to do is not to convert the `data0$value` column to a factor at all when you receive the dataset.

Comment: Although it's better not to have your numeric values converted to factor in the first place, given that they are factors, you can also do `as.numeric(as.character(data0$value))` (or, within `aes` in ggplot `as.numeric(as.character(value))`) to convert back to the correct numeric values.